# Question about having and where with my Query code

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    A.DJ_NUMBER as djNo
    ,MAX(A.ACTION) as 'SetupStarted'
    ,MIN(A.ACTION_TIME) AS 'SetupStart'
    ,MAX(B.ACTION) as 'RunStarted'
    ,MAX(B.ACTION_TIME) AS 'UpTimeStart'
    ,MAX(C.ACTION) as 'RunEnded'
    ,MAX(C.ACTION_TIME) AS 'UpTimeEnd'
    ,FORMAT(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MAX(A.ACTION_TIME), MAX(B.ACTION_TIME))/60.0,'##.##') AS Setup
    ,FORMAT(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MAX(B.ACTION_TIME), (C.ACTION_TIME))/60.0, '##.##') AS UpTime  
FROM 
    [AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] A, 
    [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] B, 
    [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] C
--WHERE (B.DJ_NUMBER = A.DJ_NUMBER AND MAX(B.ACTION_TIME) > Min(A.ACTION_TIME)) and (C.DJ_NUMBER = B.DJ_NUMBER AND MAX(C.ACTION_TIME) > MAX(B.ACTION_TIME)) 
GROUP BY  
    A.DJ_NUMBER 
HAVING 
    (B.DJ_NUMBER = A.DJ_NUMBER 
     AND MAX(B.ACTION_TIME) > Min(A.ACTION_TIME)) 
    AND (C.DJ_NUMBER = B.DJ_NUMBER 
         AND MAX(C.ACTION_TIME) > MAX(B.ACTION_TIME))
ORDER BY 
    SetupStart ASC, UpTimeEnd
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Column 'StagingDB.dbo.AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch.DJ_NUMBER' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Column 'StagingDB.dbo.AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch.DJ_NUMBER' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Column 'StagingDB.dbo.AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch.DJ_NUMBER' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: No - it is 2019. No one - NO ONE - should be using old-style joins. So start over. And the formatting of your query is garbled so correcting that will encourage others to look closer.

Comment: Sorry, SMor! I am new to this...

Comment: What is the new Style?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: why did you comented the Where clause which is defining the Join condition among the mentioned tables?

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest problems with old style joins is that you are mixing join conditions with the filtering logic of your query, because you put them both in the `where` clause. Here you tried to put all these in the `where` clause, you got an error that aggregates may not appear in the `where`, but should be in `having` and you moved all your conditions to the `having` just to get the above mentioned errors. So to fix this, leave the join conditions in the `where` clause:

```
WHERE (B.DJ_NUMBER = A.DJ_NUMBER) and (C.DJ_NUMBER = B.DJ_NUMBER)
```

and aggregations in `having`:

```
HAVING (MAX(B.ACTION_TIME) > Min(A.ACTION_TIME)) and (MAX(C.ACTION_TIME) > MAX(B.ACTION_TIME))
```

As suggested by the others in the comments, you should really stop using old style joins. Rewrite your query with `[inner join][1]`:

```
FROM 
    [AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] A
    inner join [StagingDB].[dbo].[@AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] B on B.DJ_NUMBER = A.DJ_NUMBER
    inner join [StagingDB].[dbo].[@AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] C on C.DJ_NUMBER = B.DJ_NUMBER
```

In this case you will not need `where` clause anymore and you will write aggregates in the `having`, as show above.

Also, you have an error in the expression for `UpTime` of your `select` clause - `C.ACTION_TIME` can't be left like this. It should be in aggregation function, like `MAX(C.ACTION_TIME)`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here is the solution:

```
                SELECT 

                     A.DJ_NUMBER    AS JobNo
                    ,MAX(A.ACTION) as SetupStarted
                    ,MIN(A.ACTION_TIME) AS SetupStart     
            --      ,MAX(A.ACTION_TIME) AS 'SetupStartEnd'
                    ,MAX(B.ACTION) as RunStarted
            --      ,MIN(B.ACTION_TIME) as 'RunStarted' 
                    ,MAX(B.ACTION_TIME) AS UpTimeStart
                    ,MAX(C.ACTION) as 'RunEnded'
            --      ,MIN(C.ACTION_TIME) as 'UpTimeEndStart'
                    ,MAX(C.ACTION_TIME) AS UpTimeEnd 
                    ,FORMAT(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(A.ACTION_TIME), MAX(B.ACTION_TIME))/60.0,'##.##') AS Setup
                    ,FORMAT(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MAX(B.ACTION_TIME), MAX(C.ACTION_TIME))/60.0,'##.##') AS UpTime    

            FROM
                    [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] as A
                    INNER JOIN [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] as B
                            ON (B.DJ_NUMBER = A.DJ_NUMBER  AND A.ACTION_TIME IS NOT NULL) AND B.ACTION_TIME > A.ACTION_TIME
                    INNER JOIN [StagingDB].[dbo].[AFL_MES2O_Interface_Data_arch] as C
                            ON (C.DJ_NUMBER = B.DJ_NUMBER  AND B.ACTION_TIME IS NOT NULL) AND C.ACTION_TIME > B.ACTION_TIME 
            GROUP BY  A.DJ_NUMBER
            --ORDER BY SetupStart ASC, UpTimeEnd ASC
            --where TubeJobNo = 20738056
```